# Problems saving data to DB - Fatal error: Cannot call abstract method

Tags: magento-1.8, php, database, forms

Creating a custom module Im facing many problems saving data to DB. My code look like this:

config.xml:

> ```
> <modules>
>     <Pricebinc_Shipping>
>         <version>0.1.0</version>
>     </Pricebinc_Shipping>
> </modules>
> <global>
>     <models>
>         <shipping>
>             <class>Pricebinc_Shipping_Model</class>
>             <resourceModel>shipping_resource</resourceModel>
>         </shipping>
>         <shipping_resource>
>             <class>Pricebinc_Shipping_Model_Resource</class>
>             <entities>
>                 <shipmentlist>
>                     <table>shipping_shipmentlist</table>
>                 </shipmentlist>
>             </entities>
>         </shipping_resource>
>     </models>
>     <resources>
>         <shipping_setup>
>             <setup>
>                 <module>Pricebinc_Shipping</module>
>             </setup>
>             <connection>
>                 <use>core_setup</use>
>             </connection>
>         </shipping_setup>
>         <shipping_write>
>             <connection>
>                 <use>core_write</use>
>             </connection>
>         </shipping_write>
>         <shipping_read>
>             <connection>
>                 <use>core_read</use>
>             </connection>
>         </shipping_read>
>     </resources>
> ```

In Model I have three files. a- model/shipmentlist.php

```
class Pricebinc_Shipping_Model_Shipmentlist extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract {

   public function _construct()
     {
         parent::_construct();
         $this->_init('shipping/shipmentlist');
     } 
}
```

Model/Resource/Shipmentlist.php with code:

```
class Pricebinc_Shipping_Model_Resource_Shipmentlist extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init('shipping/shipmentlist', 'autoid');
    }
}
```

autoid is my primary key.

and Model/Resource/Shipmentlist/collection.php with code:

```
class Pricebinc_Shipping_Model_Resource_Shipmentlist_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init('shipping/shipmentlist');
    }
}
```

finally I have a controller and trying to save data using the following code:

```
public function newAwbAction()
{
            $shipcontact = ''.$this->getRequest()->getPost('shipContact');
            $shipper = ''.$this->getRequest()->getPost('shipper');
            $shipaddr1 = ''.$this->getRequest()->getPost('shipAddr1');
            $shipaddr2 = ''.$this->getRequest()->getPost('shipAddr2');

            $magentoShippingModel = Mage::getModel('shipping/shipmentlist');
            $magentoShippingModel->setData('shipContact', $shipcontact);
            $magentoShippingModel->setData('shipper', $shipper);
            $magentoShippingModel->setData('shipAddr1', $shipaddr1);
            $magentoShippingModel->setData('shipAddr2', $shipaddr2);
            $magentoShippingModel->save();

}
```

Im receiving the following error -> 
Fatal error: Cannot call abstract method Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Abstract::_construct() in C:\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\app\code\local\Pricebinc\Shipping\Model\Resource\Shipmentlist.php on line 6

If I change Model/Resource/Shipmentlist.php to

```
class Pricebinc_Shipping_Model_Resource_Shipmentlist extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $mainTable = 'shipping_shipmentlist'; // check the node in the config.xml
        $idFieldName = 'autoid'; // whatever the column is named.
        $this->_init($mainTable, $idFieldName);
    }
}
```

I receive the following error -> 
Fatal error: Call to a member function getConnection() on a non-object in C:\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Db\Abstract.php on line 322

any help appreciated.

Comment: comment out `parent::_construct()` inside your resoure file and try again. note keep the first code instead of your second try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try making your `Pricebinc_Shipping_Model_Resource_Shipmentlist` class look like this:

```
class Pricebinc_Shipping_Model_Resource_Shipmentlist extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract {
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('shipping/shipmentlist', 'autoid');
    }
}
```

So don't call the `parent::_construct` method and the first parameter of `_init` should contains a slash not an underscore.

Comment: yes correct. I already commented it. But this may some time make problem. you need to remove the extra space that comes after your class name. it's my humble suggestion, great guru :)

Comment: @programmer_rkt. What space? you mean the one before the `{`. That won't hurt anything.

Comment: nope that is not what I meant. You have placed `extend `part in the next line. I have seen some cases, where that makes some problems.(in very rare instance).

Comment: OK. I'll change it, but I've been doing it like this for a very long time for class names that are long and never had an issue with it.

Comment: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/coding-standard.coding-style.html please refer this. just go below, you can see class decalration part. You can see that, it recommends my method of coding. If you refer PSR standards, you can see this there too. ALWAYS KEEP BEST PRACTICES. that is why I mentioned it. :)

Comment: @programmer_rkt. Quote from the link you mentioned "If as a result of such declarations, the line length exceeds the maximum line length, break the line before the "extends" and/or "implements" keywords, and pad those lines by one indentation level." :)

Comment: yes most probably that part we need to use when use `implement ` in our class. That will make class declaration lengthy. So we can adopt that method. But in the above case, we need to go for the primary recommendation. I think when I answer here, I always try to follow best practices. If you follow that too, a lot of code become good :)

Comment: I followed the best practices...the line went over max chars (80) so...

Comment: as an example, here class declaration open bracket `{` comes along with class declaration. but the best practice is, place that bracket always in next line. I know some time it is difficult to answer like that. still it worths

Comment: he he you have counted it ! unbelievable. Though zend framework uses 80 as limit, php uses 120 characters. The thing is code should look good that's it. Any how its not relevant here. If you want, we can talk this in twitter  :)